# Searching for Brahmopanishad

Tags: upanishads

My great grandmother used to chant Brahmopanishad. Its wordings were: Kalatrayaa bodhitam brahma; Sarvakaala bodhitam brahma..."Could someone tell me where I can find this upanishad?

Comment: Are you looking for english  language version only OR Hindi will do ? Pls. mention about the language.

Comment: Do u want the Upanishad given in my answer? Do u want the Sanskrit as well?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the English translation of the Brahmopanishad](http://www.astrojyoti.com/brahmaupanishad.htm) from Krishna Yajur Veda.

It starts with Shaunka questioning Piplada Rishi.

> . Om ! Shaunaka, householder of fame, once asked Bhagavan Pippalada of
>   Angira’s family: In this body, the divine city of Brahman, installed,
>   how do they create ? Whose glory does this constitute ? Who is he who
>   became all this glory ?

Comment: Does this upanishat have " Kalatrayaa bodhitam brahma; Sarvakaala bodhitam brahma" ?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma No, I think OP need to verify is s/he looking for Brahma Upanishad.

Comment: @Pandya See my message for u in the Room for Pandya and Rickross..(delete this one once u have read it)